# Django - Rebuild a project database

Tags: django, django-1.11

For some reasons, I droped my database by using MYSQL command DROP DATABASE.

I use Python3.6 and Django 1.11 with MySQL database.

So now, how am I supposed to rebuid my database/tables following my models.py ?

I simply used makemigrations but I have some errors like if Django didn't forget any tables.

```
manage.py makemigrations

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 292, in query
_mysql.connection.query(self, query)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'agora.start_games' doesn't exist")
```

For information, 'start' is my only app in my django project. I know this table doesn't exist, I just want to make all rebuilt.

Then, I tried :

```
root@raspberrypi:/home/django-project/agora# python3.6 manage.py migrate --run-syncdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 101, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 250, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 50, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorvalue
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 247, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 411, in _query
    rowcount = self._do_query(q)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 374, in _do_query
    db.query(q)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 292, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'agora.start_games' doesn't exist")

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 355, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 327, in execute
    self.check()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 359, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 62, in _run_checks
    issues.extend(super(Command, self)._run_checks(**kwargs))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 346, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 81, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 16, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 26, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 254, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 405, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 398, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/django-project/agora/agora/urls.py", line 21, in <module>
    url(r'^start/', include('start.urls')),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py", line 50, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/django-project/agora/start/urls.py", line 17, in <module>
    from . import views
  File "/home/django-project/agora/start/views.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .forms import MinimumRegisterForm, GamesRegisterForm
  File "/home/django-project/agora/start/forms.py", line 26, in <module>
    class GamesRegisterForm(forms.Form):
  File "/home/django-project/agora/start/forms.py", line 28, in GamesRegisterForm
    for game in Games.objects.all().order_by('title'):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 250, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1102, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 53, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 876, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 80, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 101, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 250, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 50, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorvalue
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 247, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 411, in _query
    rowcount = self._do_query(q)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 374, in _do_query
    db.query(q)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 292, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'agora.start_games' doesn't exist")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem is solved. To those who get the same problem, this is my solution.

1)Backup your Django project and delete the folder

2) Create a new Django project with the same name

3) Create new Django apps with the same names

4) Import and replace your settings.py

5) Enter makemigrations then migrate commands

-> Database is now restored (create a new database manually is required before)

6) You can now remove this project and import your backup project

7) Enter makemigrations then migrate commands

-> The databased with models are now fully restored

/!\ Off course, all the data are lost and I have to recreate for example an superuser for the Django admin panel.

Answer (score 2):

First step is to create the database again in MySQL, and setup the credentials:

```
mysql> create database foo; grant all on foo.* to someuser with password 'foopass';
```

Then, setup your `settings.py` file with the information above:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'foo',
        'USER': 'someuser',
        'PASSWORD': 'foopass',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
    }
}
```

Next, run `migrate` with `--run-syncdb` option:

```
python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb
```

This should setup your database correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But --syncdb is not recognized as a valid argument. May be because of Django version 1.11 ?

Comment: Sorry, its [`run-syncdb`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-migrate).

Comment: Ok, but It display the same error message, telling that 'agora.start_games' doesn't exist.

Comment: Update your question and add the entire traceback.

Comment: The reason why its not working is because you are calling the ORM before it is loaded, by this line: `for game in Games.objects.all().order_by('title')`; when this line is evaluated, the database is not yet created so the exception is thrown.